# Setting NFS mount point directory permissions and owner

Tags: linux, networking, centos, nfs

I currently have an NFS mounted

```
website.com:/var/sites/backups0   /mnt/backup nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

The problem is, this mounts 777 permissions and I want it to be 700, the directory is set to 700.

dmask and dir_mode both are invalid options, the man page didnt say anything about mode permissions either.  How do I lock this down to 700 root access only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions in this case come from the remote host, `website.com`. The mount point permissions are superseded by the remote filesystem's permissions.

If you need to prevent others from accessing it, mount it one level deeper, ie `/mnt/b/backup`, and `chmod 700 /mnt/b` beforehand. (You could change perms on `/mnt` but probably that's going to interfere with access to other mount points.)

Comment: I already did that to some degree locking down mnt to 770 which works just fine since it's not often anything is mounted.  

I think I can also lock down the permissions on website.com so that should get me everything I need.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great! No worries. :-)