# NFS share: what defines "other"'s permissions?

Tags: permissions, nfs

I am mounting an NFS share (v3, from my Synology NAS) on a FreeBSD 10.1 box. This works (i.e. it does *not* seem to be a UID/GID issue), but I always get 777 permissions when I mount the share. I need this to be 770.

This is `/etc/exports` on the NAS:

```
DataTomb> cat /etc/exports
/volume1/nas_share     192.0.2.1(rw,async,no_wdelay,root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1024,anongid=100)
```

And this is `/etc/fstab` on the FreeBSD box:

```
nas.domain.tld:/volume1/nas_share   /var/nas_share   nfs   rw  0   0
```

Here is the mount point (on FreeBSD) **before** the share is mounted:

```
# ll -n /var/
...
drwxrwx---   2 80  100   512B Aug 22 09:38 nas_share
....
```

The directory `nas_share` is empty:

```
# ll -n /var/nas_share/
total 8
drwxrwx---   2 80  100   512B Aug 22 09:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 0   0     1.0K Aug 18 22:16 ..
```

This is what it looks like **after** the share is mounted:

```
 # ll -n /var/
...
drwxrwxrwx   5 0   0    4.0K Aug 18 22:34 nas_share
...
```

And within the directory:

```
# ll -n /var/nas_share/
total 56
drwxrwxrwx   5 0     0     4.0K Aug 18 22:34 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 0     0     1.0K Aug 18 22:16 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 1030  100   284B Aug 18 22:23 .htaccess
...
drwxrwxrwx   5 1030  100   4.0K Aug 18 23:01 user1
...
```

Where is the `rwx` for "other" coming from? How can I change this to 770? This should be permanent (i.e. I cannot do this every time the share is mounted).

This is actually pretty close to [1], but the answer to that question seems contradictory to me (first it states that the mount point permissions are not relevant, then it suggests to change the mount point permissions...)

Am I missing something obvious?

[1] [Setting NFS mount point directory permissions and owner](https://serverfault.com/q/117384/48229)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to set that on the directory in the NAS.

If your NAS won't let you change it, then you'll have to temporarily replace root_squash with no_root_squash in the options, and then *maybe* it'll work from NFS...

```
cd /var/nas_share/
chmod o= .
```